# Is a newly created Docker container associated with a new cgroup?

Tags: linux, docker, cgroups

Is a newly created Docker container associated with a new cgroup?

After all the processes inside a container finishes running, and the container is restarted again sometime later, will it be associated with a new cgroup or still the same cgroup as before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and that is most probably under system.slice.
You can change the `slice` for all docker containers.

This can be viewed using `systemd-cgls`, or check for `cat /proc/PROCESS_ID/cgroup`

Comment: Thank you. Which of my two questions do you answer yes to?

Comment: Is a newly created Docker container associated with a new cgroup?

Comment: What does `slice ` mean?

Comment: slice is high level organisation in cgroups.

Comment: I am still not sure what it means.

Comment: So, cgroups are grouped in many categories, usually by the process. that is under docker or systemd process. Check with systemd-cgls command or check file `/proc/PID/cgroup`